# Activating the ComboBox when the CheckBox is checked

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make UserForm where if CheckBox is marked the ComboBox will be allowed to be clicked. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    ComboBox3.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

It doesn`t work and I have no idea why.

Comment: shouldn't it be `ComboBox3.Enabled = True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your narrative

> if CheckBox is marked

I'd assume you want to react to any checkbox status change, then you need a Checkbox event handler

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    ComboBox3.Enabled = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that when the UserForm is initialized, the ComboBox3 is disabled and it should only be enabled when CheckBox1 is clicked else it should remain disabled.

You will need to place following two codes on the UserForm Module.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If CheckBox1 Then
    Me.ComboBox3.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.ComboBox3.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```